# Get input request and insert it in database laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am new fan of Laravel framework. can you tell me how to get input in my post method and insert it as an atribute 'cli' in my table 'demandes'.

```
class DemandeController extends Controller
{
    protected $demandeRepository;
    protected $demandeGestion;
    protected $compteRepository;

    protected $nbrPerPage = 4;

    public function search(SearchRequest $request)
        {        
            $mc = $request->input('mc');
            $demandes = $this->demandeRepository->search($mc);
            $links = $demandes->render();
            $etape = $request->input('etape');
            return view('demandes.liste', compact('demandes', 'links'))->with('etape',$etape);
        }

 public function update(DemandeRequest $request, $id)
    {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $inputs = $this->demandeGestion->get_inputs($request,$user);

            $demande=  $this->demandeRepository->update($id, $inputs);
             return redirect('demande')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $demande->objet . " a été modifié.");


             //return redirect('demandes.liste')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $request->input('objet') . " a été enregistrée.");
    }

public function store(DemandeRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $user->id]);
        $demande = $this->demandeRepository->store($inputs);

        return redirect('demande')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $demande->objet . " a été créé.");
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

## Dido

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to use [Laravel Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models) anytime I work with data. If you're able to, here's how I would do it with the use of a model

Laravel Folder/app/Demande.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Demande extends Model {

}
```

Sample `store` request in Laravel Folder/app/Http/Controllers/DemandeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// Models
use App\Demande;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DemandeController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $demande = new Demande;
        $demande->cli = $request->cli;
        $demande->objet = $request->objet;
        $demande->user_id = Auth::id();
        $demande->some_other_attribute = $request->some_other_attribute;
        $demande->save();

        return redirect('demande')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $demande->objet . " a été créé.");
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work for your needs, I'd need to know more about your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks too much for your response. So, unfortunatly it doesn't work because I have also defined the function store() in my file DemandeRepository.

```
public function store($inputs)
    {
        $demande = new $this->demande;
        $this->save($demande, $inputs);
        return $demande;
    }

private function save(Demande $demande, Array $inputs)

    {

        $demande->objet = $inputs['objet'];

        $demande->save();

    }
```

My Models :

```
class Demande extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['objet','etude','user_id','role','mc','num_tf','val_exp','nom_exp','nom_gar'];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use AdldapUserModelTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function demandes(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Demande');
    }
}
```

My file DemandeRequest:

```
class DemandeRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'objet' => 'required|max:80',
 ];
    }
}



 public function update(DemandeRequest $request, $id)
    {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $inputs = $this->demandeGestion->get_inputs($request,$user);

            $demande=  $this->demandeRepository->update($id, $inputs);
             return redirect('demande')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $demande->objet . " a été modifié.");


             //return redirect('demandes.liste')->withOk("Le dossier  " . $request->input('objet') . " a été enregistrée.");
    }
```

My class DemandeGestion

```
class DemandeGestion
{
    protected $demande;
    public function __construct(Demande $demande)
        {
            $this->demande = $demande;
        }

    public function get_inputs(DemandeRequest $request, User $user){
                if($user->role=='ETUDE'){
                        $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $user->id,'etat' => $user->role]);

                    }else{
                            $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $user->id]);
                        }
                        return $inputs;
    }
}
```